# Value For A Key In A Hashmap Being Set To Value Of Another Key

Tags: java, hashmap, maps

I am having issues with the values of different keys in a hashmap I created. Somehow, the values are being overwritten by the most current added value.

For example:

```
map.put("String1", "123")
map.put("String2", "456")
System.out.println(map.get("String1")); //would print 456
```

My hashmap is:

```
Map<String, Testing> systems = new HashMap<>();
```

Testing:

```
class Testing {

    private double[] ap;
    private double[] dcg;
    private double[] ndcg;

    public Testing(double[] _ap, double[] _dcg, double[] _ndcg){

        ap = _ap;
        dcg = _dcg;
        ndcg = _ndcg;

    }

    public double[] getAp(){

        return ap;

    }

    public double[] getDcg(){

         return dcg;

    }

    public double[] getNdcg(){

        return ndcg;

    }

}
```

Here is the problem (f is a File):

```
systems.put(f.getName(), new Testing(ap, dcg, ndcg));

if(f.getName().equals("input.Flab9atdnN.gz") || 
    f.getName().equals("input.apl9lt.gz")) {
        System.out.println(f.getName() + ": " + 
        systems.get(f.getName()).getAp()[5]);
}

if(f.getName().equals("input.Flab9atdnN.gz")) {
    System.out.println(f.getName().equals("input.Flab9atdnN.gz"));
    double temp = systems.get("input.apl9lt.gz").getAp()[5];
    double temp2 = systems.get("input.Flab9atdnN.gz").getAp()[5];
    System.out.println("input.Flab9atdnN.gz: " + temp2 + ". input.apl9lt.gz: 
    " + temp);
}
```

The first print gives different values for key "input.Flab9atdnN.gz" and key "input.apl9lt.gz".

```
System.out.println(f.getName() + ": " + systems.get(f.getName()).getAp() 
[5]);
```

The last print statement gives the same value for key "input.Flab9atdnN.gz" but gives key "input.apl9lt.gz" key "input.Flab9atdnN.gz"'s value. Key "input.Flab9atdnN.gz" is added to the hashmap after key "input.apl9lt.gz" thus anything added after key "input.Flab9atdnN.gz" would give that new keys value to "input.Flab9atdnN.gz" as well.

```
double temp = systems.get("input.apl9lt.gz").getAp()[5];
double temp2 = systems.get("input.Flab9atdnN.gz").getAp()[5];
System.out.println("input.Flab9atdnN.gz: " + temp2 + ". input.apl9lt.gz: " + 
temp);
```

Any clue why this is and any possible work around? I tried doing something similar with lists and had the same problem. I tried not using Testing as well.

Thank you.

Edit (for inputs):

input.apl9lt.gz

0.160837098024862
0.03075251487336594
0.22437008086531643
0.1971910732696186
0.26775040012743095
9.256258391747239E-4
0.1348288884102969
0.04098977989693765
0.22076261792825694
0.14351330413359978
0.4326923076923077
0.07127127472804279
4.552325182365065E-5
0.010058991520632703
0.013241228159087674
0.010137295467368818
0.16308220490382738
0.013974532767649097
0.1591821903406855
0.03546054590978735
0.017811035142771457
0.09931683119953653
0.0012300123001230013
3.2100667693888034E-5
0.13463869607114665
0.056660951442691745
0.009024064171122994
0.00111158621285874
0.19147531389263409
6.058415656054187E-4
0.15122464967762936
0.017945455244915694
0.24100308685261787
6.295914132164171E-4
0.41666666666666663
0.16054778554778554
0.12606805722666745
0.03122700118062138
0.05840908368719257
0.06151876506910154
8.167932696234583E-5
0.48663786619303134
0.0017420658249683476
0.20520161886380303
7.111269849728675E-5
0.1157176972265951
0.28587824256374156
0.032836748137528377
0.04182754182754183
0.02944176265259386

input.Flab9atdnN.gz

0.4550531747779656
0.11354712610736152
0.4465970245283123
0.39990864084973815
0.23410193071725469
8.08015513897867E-5
0.11287817139653589
0.02255268670973833
0.30038335608865446
0.21267974099603318
0.6041666666666666
0.15726821262566176
0.15690222729126874
1.5053439710973956E-4
0.0843584401155248
0.5027027027027027
0.1873237718924946
0.005660813678763912
0.012321170992537366
0.0529994153272247
0.04489848129896188
0.016508461433080466
0.0
1.0736065674698053E-4
0.07164253590778259
0.14083889573189318
0.024676040805073064
0.16099898114516484
0.16509562037628656
0.06488409960391041
0.22263263699157246
0.0568843663526689
0.4175364417422477
0.1106842493991619
0.15555555555555556
0.5416666666666666
0.4654817731306396
0.0930344930767678
0.344114561968089
0.1882981402539536
0.11698973634619976
0.4533746137676584
0.3389765988389732
0.475199277730597
0.08708693608991427
0.34790332410690694
0.035929746042875826
0.08056424630498706
0.20352743561030237
0.12758565977230674

Read these into a double array (size 50). To use the Testing class, just remove dcg and ndcg.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code only has 1 `put` call, so you're not showing code to reproduce the problem of having two entries in the map.

Comment: @andreas updated

Comment: You still haven't provided **Complete, Verifiable** example. Please create small runnable test program that shows the problem. More than likely, when you write reduced code to reproduce the problem is a standalone program, you'll find your error yourself. If not, we can then run and **debug** the code to help you find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapPutExample {

    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("String1", "123");
        map.put("String2", "456");
        System.out.println(map.get("String1")); //would print 456
    }
}
```

prints

> 123

So: No it's not.

You haven't provided the actual code where we can see how you add elements to the map but given the fact that `Testing` contains arrays I suppose that you don't initiialize new arrays when setting its values from the file. So you do something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapPutExample {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, char[]> map = new HashMap<>();

        char[] buffer = new char[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (char) ('a' + i);
        }
        map.put("String1", buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (char) ('k' + i);
        }
        map.put("String2", buffer);
        System.out.println(map.get("String1")); //would print klmnopqrst
    }
}
```

This actually prints

> klmnopqrst

You need to create new arrays and set these to the `Testing` instances that you add to the map:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapPutExample {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, char[]> map = new HashMap<>();

        char[] buffer = new char[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (char) ('a' + i);
        }
        map.put("String1", buffer);
        buffer = new char[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (char) ('k' + i);
        }
        map.put("String2", buffer);
        System.out.println(map.get("String1")); //would print klmnopqrst
    }
}
```

This is printing

> abcdefghij

Comment: the first part was a visual example and no where did I say that was my issue. I will take a look into your mention about arrays. That could be it. Thank you.